# Git tracking remote branch not working with git push?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm using Git Version 1.9.5

I want to understand how remote branch tracking really work.

I create a local branch to track my remote master branch:

```
git checkout -b feature-a origin/master
```

Once I ran the above command Git show me the following message
"Branch feature-a set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature-a' "

Now I run the following command:

```
git pull
```

It seems the tracking is working, Git knows which remote branch to pull from.

Now I create a new file test.txt and commit and push.

```
git push
```

It show me the following message:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Everything up-to-date
```

My question:  Is the "git push" also work in remote branch tracking or only work with "git pull" ?

Lots of article online they state you can do "git push" with remote branch tracking.

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning.  Your push happened.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it doesn't do the push.  I have two copies of the remote repository on my computer to mimic a two developer.  

When I switched to the other directory on my computer and do a git pull from origin/master.  It doesn't have the file I pushed earlier from the other directory (which has the tracking branch).

Comment: It pushed the branch.  If you want the changes to appear in master, you need to merge the branch into master.  From your `master` branch: `git pull; git merge feature-a; git push`.  The changes will now be visible in master.

Comment: I think if that's the behaviour of remote branch tracking then, it's correct.  This will prevent accidental push to origin/master by running "git push" command.  It has to be "git push origin feature-a:master"  in order to work.  

Considering working with Git workflow and I always did the "git checkout -b myfeature origin/master"  to create my local feature branch base on origin/master branch copy.

Comment: Yes. the `checkout -b` creates a branch based on the branch you specify on the next argument -- in your case you are creating a branch based on `origin/master`.  It does not cause `feature-a` to be tied to `origin/master`.  That relationship would be astonishing.